# Reference request: Gronwall's inequality with negative sign(s)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

The following claim is a consequence of Gronwall's theorem

> Let $x \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ with $x(0) = 0$ be a continuously differentiable function, whose derivative satisfies
>   $$ \dot x(t) \le a(t)x(t) + C$$
>   with a constant $C \ge 0$ and an integrable function $a \colon [0,\infty) \to (-\infty,0]$.
>   Then we have
>   $$ x(t) \le tC $$

See e.g. [this blog post](http://landonkavlie.wordpress.com/2013/03/27/gronwalls-inequality/).

Gronwall's theorem can be found in many text books; however, all those that I looked at only considered the case of nonnegative $x$ and $a$, whereas I need $x$ to be arbitrary and $a$ to be nonpositive.

**Q**: Is there a (standard) text book (which can be cited) that treats this general case?

Comment: In your statement $a$ is already non-positive. What are you asking exactly?

Comment: @GitGud: I've rephrased my question.

Comment: The sign of $a$ is irrelevant to Gronwall's lemma (as shown in the link you provide). And the usual proof of G's lemma yields the result you are looking for. Do you know the usual proof of G's lemma and did you try to adapt it to the situation?

Comment: @Did: I'm not sure I've even seen the *usual proof*.

Comment: Then what is the point of asking about *refinements* of G's lemma?

Comment: I'm asking about a *reference*, because I want to write "[..] follows from an application of Gronwall's lemma, which states [..]; for a proof, see XXX", where XXX would ideally be a standard textbook. I do not want to provide a proof in my work. I think I've made that perfectly clear by repeatedly asking for a textbook instead of a proof, and labelling the question as "reference request" (while I only now added the tag, the title has reflected this from the beginning).

Comment: Have you founded that reference? I am currently writing a paper and would also like to refer to the ineq. but Evan's book that Did suggested (appendix B.2.j) also assumes nonnegative $a(t)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching several books on ODEs I think you could refer to a stronger result, the so called **comparison lemma**  which appears in appendix E.4 of

[1] W.J. Terrell, *Stability and stabilization*, Princeton University Press, 2009.

> **Lemma E.4** [1] (Comparison Lemma)
>
> Suppose $w(t, u)$ is continuous on a connected open set $\Omega$ in
>   $R^2$ and the scalar equation  $$\dot{u} = w(t, u)\qquad\qquad(E.3)$$ 
>   has a unique solution for each initial condition $(t_0, u_0)$. If $u(t)$ is a solution of (E.3) on $[a, b]$ and $v(t)$ is a solution of the
>   differential inequality  $$\dot{v}\leq w(t,v)$$  on $[a, b)$ with
>   $v(a) \leq u(a)$, then   $$   v(t) \leq  u(t),\qquad a \leq t < b.$$

In your case
$$\dot{x}\leq a(t)x(t)+C\leq C$$
as $a(t)x(t)\leq 0$ for all $t$ by definition. The solution of $\dot{u}=C$ is $u(t)=u(0)+Ct$ and for $u(0)=0\geq x(0)$ the conditions of Lemma E.4 of [1] hold true and therefore
$$x(t)\leq u(t)=Ct.$$

---

The above analysis holds true as long as $x(t)\geq 0$ for all$t\in[0,\infty)$. 
If $x$ is negative over some intervals then the above Lemma cannot be directly applied but needs a modification.

We consider two cases:

a) If $x(t)<0$ then  $x(t)<0\leq Ct$  since $C\geq 0$.

b) For $x(t)>0$ due to continuity (and starting from $0$) there exists a time instant $$t^*=\inf\{s\in[0,t):x(t^*)=0\}$$ which is the nearest time up to $t$ for which $x(t^*)=0$. Obviously $x(s)\geq 0$ for all $s\in[t^*,t]$ and we can  apply Lemma E.4 as described before in $[t^*,t]$ to prove that $$x(t)\leq C(t-t^*)\leq Ct$$

Comment: Thank you. That's a very nice theorem!

Comment: @anonymous Thanks. Seeing my post after one year, I realized that you have not explicitly stated that $x(t)\geq 0$ for all $t$. This means that $a(t)x(t)\leq 0$ only if $x(t)\geq 0$. If $x$ is negative over some intervals then the above Lemma cannot be directly applied but needs a modification. You should consider two cases: a) For $x(t)<0$ then condition $x(t)\leq Ct$ obviously holds for $C\geq 0$ b) For $x(t)>0$ due to continuity (and starting from $0$) there exists a time instant $t^*=\inf\{s\in[0,t):x(t^*)=0\}$ where we can  apply Lemma E.4 as described since $x(s)\geq 0$ within $[t^*,t]$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the *usual proof* of (the differential form of) Gronwall's lemma. One assumes that some differentiable function $x$ is such that $$x'(t)\leqslant a(t)x(t).$$
Then one considers $A(t)=\displaystyle\int_0^ta(s)\mathrm ds$ and one notes that
$$(\mathrm e^{-A(t)}x(t))'=\mathrm e^{-A(t)}\cdot(x'(t)-a(t)x(t))\leqslant0,
$$
hence, for every $t\geqslant0$,
$$\mathrm e^{-A(t)}x(t)\leqslant\mathrm e^{-A(0)}x(0),
$$
that is,
$$
x(t)\leqslant x(0)\exp\left(\int_0^ta(s)\mathrm ds\right).
$$
This was Gronwall's lemma. Now, the task is to adapt the brilliant idea used in its proof to the setting you are interested in! Your hypotheses are that
$$
x'(t)\leqslant a(t)x(t)+C,
$$
and $x(0)=0$, hence...

Comment: That's a very understandable proof and indeed easily adapted to my situation, thank you. Do you know of a standard textbook that employs this proof?

Comment: Please show the adaptation.

Comment: Well, if I rename my $x$ to $u$, then my $u$ satisfies $\dot u(t) \le a(t)u(t) + C$. If I now set $x(t) = u(t) - tC$, then I only need to show $x \le 0$, which I can do by means of the above theorem: We have $x'(t) = a(t)u(t) \le a(t)x(t)$ (since $u(t) \ge x(t)$), and we're done (both $x$ and $u$ vanish at zero).

Comment: Indeed. Well done.

Comment: This still does not answer my question in which standard textbook I can find this theorem or its proof, though.

Comment: Every textbook with "Gronwall" in it should have it. Or [the obvious](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gronwall%27s_inequality#Proof).

Comment: I cannot cite wikipedia. And what you say is just not true: I've gone through over a dozen books with proofs for Gronwall's lemma now, and each one uses positivity at some point, see e.g. http://books.google.com/books?id=yfY2uGROVrUC&pg=PA146

Comment: The page you link to proves G's INTEGRAL lemma. Your question uses G's DIFFERENTIAL lemma, for which positivity is offtopic, as we just saw. Well, if WP is not enough (which I cannot fathom why) AND if the proof I gave above is not enough (which I cannot fathom why either), I believe Evans does it in the appendices of his book "Partial Differential Equations". Be warned though, you will find the same proof as above.