# Does $f(x) \le f(0) - c\int_0^x f(u)du$ imply $f(x) \le f(0)e^{-cx}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ be a continuous function satisfying $f(x) \le f(0) - c\int_0^x f(u)du$ for all $x\in[0,1]$ where $c>0$. Is it true that $f(x) \le f(0)e^{-cx}$ for all $x \in [0,1]$? I was trying to use the Gronwall inequality but all I found require $c \le 0$.

Comment: This answer will solve your problem: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1541061/28743

Comment: @nbubis Any hint? I tried to use the comparison lemma by letting $g(t) = \pm\int_0^xf(u)du$ to convert the integral inequality to the differential inequality but it does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no**. Set 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 1- \lambda x \quad (0 \le x < \lambda^{-1}) \\
0  \quad (\lambda^{-1} < x < 1 - \lambda^{-1}) \\
\delta \lambda x - \delta \lambda + \delta  \quad(1 - \lambda^{-1} < x \le 1)
\end{cases}
$$
Pick $\delta$ as close to 1 as you want. By making $\lambda$ large, you can make the inequality in the assumption hold for any $c > 0$. But $f(1) = \delta$ regardless of $\lambda$.

Therefore the assumption does not even imply that there exists $d > 0$ such that $f(x) \le e^{-dx}$ for all $x$.

Comment: @flyingwith With the stronger assumption $$ f(x_1) \le f(x_0) - c \int_{x_0}^{x_1} f(s) ds$$ for all $0 \le x_0 < x_1 \le 1$ the conclusion holds.

Comment: May I know whether you have a proof for the inequality under the stronger assumption?

Comment: Yes I do. You can use Dini derivatives, e.g.. Please ask this as a separate question.